Spring batch test : cannot find a bean
I'm writing tests for spring batch. But my test fails because it cannot find a JobRepository bean from application context. I thought @SpringBatchTest was supposed to load this bean but it doesn't work. I added BatchAutoConfiguration.class but didn't work either
When I use @SpringBootTest it works fine because this JobRepository implementation is part of auto configuration  but I don't want to load the whole context
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

I have a basic Spring batch configuration :
@Configuration
public class ConfigBatch {

    @Autowired
    JobDurationListener jobDurationListener;

    @Autowired
    DataRepository repository;


    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        //create task executor
        return executor;
    }


    @Bean
    public DataItemWriter dataItemWriter(DataService dataService) {
        return new DataItemWriter(dataService);
    }

    @Bean
    public Job sampleJob(JobRepository jobRepository, Step sampleStep) {
        return new JobBuilder("job", jobRepository)
                .listener(jobDurationListener)
                .start(step)
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public Step sampleStep(JobRepository jobRepository,
                            PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, DataService dataService) {
        return new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository)
                .<Data, Data>chunk(10, transactionManager)
                .reader(reader(analyseService))
                .processor(asyncProcessor())
                .writer(asyncWriter(dataService))
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Data,Data> processor() {
        return new ItemProcessor<Data, Data>() {
            @Override
            public Analyse process(Data item) throws Exception {
                return data;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public AsyncItemWriter<Data> asyncWriter(DataService dataService) {
        var asyncWriter = new AsyncItemWriter<Data>();
        asyncWriter.setDelegate(writer(dataService));
        return asyncWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    public AsyncItemProcessor asyncProcessor() {
        var asyncProcessor = new AsyncItemProcessor<Data, Data>();
        asyncProcessor.setDelegate(processor());
        asyncProcessor.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
        return asyncProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Data> reader(DataService dataService) {
        return new JpaAnalyseItemReader(dataService);
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Data> writer(DataService dataService) {
        return new JpaAnalyseWriter(dataService);
    }
    

}

Here is my test class :
@DataJpaTest
@Import({ConfigBatch.class, BatchAutoConfiguration.class})
@SpringBatchTest
public class BatchTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    @Test
    void myTest() throws Exception {
        jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(job);
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
        assertEquals("COMPLETED", jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
    }


}



I thought @SpringBatchTest was supposed to load this bean but it doesn't work

@SpringBatchTest only loads test utilities, but not infrastructure beans. You need to define the job repository in the test context or import a configuration class that defines it. There is a note about this in the javadocs of @SpringBatchTest:
The test context must contain a JobRepository and a
JobLauncher beans for this annotation to properly set up test utilities.


When I use @SpringBootTest it works fine because this JobRepository implementation is part of auto configuration but I don't want to load the whole context

In that case, you need to define the JobRepository in the test context.
